# Notepad++ Regular Expression Find & Replace Across New Line Characters

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++, preg-replace

I'm trying to convert a bunch of text in a file into a format that can go into a CSV file. I'm trying to do this with Notepad++ by coming up with a regular expression that can do the conversions.
I have a text file in the following format:

```
Company Name 1
First: Sally
Last: Cohen

Company Name 2
First: Janny
Last: Smith

First: John
Last: Dough
```

Some fields don't have a company name, but I'm trying to convert it into the following format:
REPLACEMENT:

```
"Company Name 1";"Sally";"Cohen"
"Company Name 2";"Janny";"Smith"
"";"John";"Dough"
```

What is the right regular expression combination for the search and replace fields in Notepad++ to do this across new lines?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: I tried a bunch of random things I got from Stack Overflow that didn't work! I'm not yet up to par with regular expressions to get Notepad++ to be able to do this. If you could give me some insight or direction that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Regex

Find what: `(?:\r\n)*(.*)\r\nFirst: (.+)\r\nLast: (.+)\r\n`

Replace with: `"\1";"\2";"\3"\r\n`

## Result

[image]

## Detail

1. `(?:\r\n)*`: match but not group, remove `\r\n` before Company name or First
2. `(.*)\r\n`: match company name, `.*` means it can be empty
3. `First: (.+)\r\n` and `Last: (.+)\r\n`: just match the first name and last name, `.+` means it should be least one letter

Comment: That works -- thanks so much for your help, @Brett7533!