# Merger lines in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text file that contains the address on two lines, it will look like this:

```
Company Name
Address: 123 AnyStreet
AnyCity, ST 12345
Company Name
Address: 123 AnyStreet
AnyCity, ST 12345
Company Name
Address: 123 AnyStreet
AnyCity, ST 12345
```

I would like to get it to look like this:

```
Company Name Address: 123 AnyStreet AnyCity, ST 12345
Company Name Address: 123 AnyStreet AnyCity, ST 12345
Company Name Address: 123 AnyStreet AnyCity, ST 12345
```

I can get the text selected with `(?-s)^(Address:).*\R.*` but can't seem to figure out the replace expression.

Comment: Try `^(Addres:.*)\R(.*)` => `$1 $2`

Comment: maybe you mean `\R(Addres:.*)\R(.*)`, also option `. matches newline` must not be checked

Comment: `\R^(Address:.+)\R(.+)` => `<space>$1 $2` - this should give you what you want. Replace `<space>` with literal space character.

Comment: my other answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48653409/notepad-regular-expression-find-replace-across-new-line-characters)

Comment: Thanks for editing my post, worked like a champ! My next bit of manipulation would be to parse the City, ST 12345 so that it would be City \t ST \t 12345 so I can sort by City, ST and Zip when saved as a CSV.

Comment: @Huntereth Do you want to say my top comment solution works, right? I will post once you confirm for you to accept.

Answer (score 0):

Find what: [`\R(Address:.*)\R([^,\n]*), ST (.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/HXFdMD/5)

Replace with: `\1 \2\t\3\t\4`

Answer (score 0):

Search for `\R(?=A)` and replace with   space.

It uses a lookahead.

[The Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YJcuct/1)

Answer (score 0):

Not a fancy solution, but it works just fine:

> ```
> Find What: ^(.*?)\r\n(.*?)\r\n(.*?),\s+(.*?)\s+(\d+)$
> Replace with: $1\t$2\t$3\t$4\t$5
> ```

This already split City, ST and Zip as requested in comments:

> My next bit of
>   manipulation would be to parse the City, ST 12345 so that it would be
>   City \t ST \t 12345 so I can sort by City, ST and Zip when saved as a
>   CSV. –